# 2d grid interpolation

Tags: grid, 2d, interpolation

I have a task of interpolating a 2d array of NxM to AxB, where A > N and B > M. The point of it is building a simple color coded image of an array (heat map).

Do I understand correctly that, for example, an array of 3x3 (all known values)

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

Should be interpolated in, say, 6x6 in this manner

```
A x B x x C
x x x x x x
D x E x x F
x x x x x x
x x x x x x
G x H x x I
```

where x marks unknown yet interpolated value, right?

Can this be done in two nested for loops? I found [bilinear interpolation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation), but having some trouble with adapting it to (i, j) of resulted array loop. Any advices? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Should be interpolated in, say, 6x6 in this manner..."* That's a judgment call. As I'm sure you've discovered there are many resampling methods - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28bitmap%29 - and the one you choose depends on a lot of factors.

Comment: Even considering my heat map task? Result I need is similar to this http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Bilininterp.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a library like .NET, Qt or SDL to do it, it's a common application task.

If you want to implement it yourself, read about [Bilinear filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_filtering) rather than bilinear interpolation. "Interpolation" generally means you interpolate just between two values - once you have an image, it's called filtering.

Consider nicer looking filters such as bicubic, too.

Comment: Is it right way to getting something like this http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Bilininterp.png ? Does it matter that values in my array are not actual colors yet?

Comment: Yeah, your example pic is exactly bilinear filtering, but it only shows filtering *in a 2x2 subarray* of your source data. If you do the same thing for every 2x2 subarray, you're done.

Comment: If values in my array are not actual colors, you can map them to colors first, then interpolate the colors. Or you could interpolate the values, then map the interpolated values to colors. The two will produce different effects (the example pic is using the latter method, which can be more appropriate for a heatmap). Also your example pic has a posterization effect that I'm assuming you don't want.